# Base to Derived To another Base cast in constructor segfault — invalid code or compiler bug?

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, language-lawyer, virtual-inheritance

This code gives me a segfault sometimes or invalid result on GCC/Clang. However, it works fine on MSVC & ICC. I'm not sure if my code is invalid from the eyes of the standard or if it is a compiler bug in GCC/Clang.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
    virtual void func() {}
    void* junk = nullptr;
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    B() {
        T* cp = static_cast<T*>(this);
        A* a = cp;
        printf("%p\n", a);
    }
};

struct C : virtual A, B<C>
{
    C() : A(), B<C>() {}
};

int main() {
    C c;

    A* ptr = &c;
    printf("%p\n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

One such incorrect result on Godbolt (Clang). Both pointers are a result of cast to same base A and as such should give same address:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
0x7fff9fa82608
0x7fff9fa82510
```

I have debugged it to understand the root cause behind it. The static_cast<T*>(this) is fine. But the pointer conversion from T* -> A* requires the vtable to get the offset of the base class since A it is a virtual base class. You can see this if you compile this function on godbolt:

```
A& func(C& c) {
    return c;
}
```

Generated code:

```
func(C&):
mov     rax, rdi                     % rax = address of input C object
mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi]         % rcx = load vtable of C
add     rax, qword ptr [rcx - 24]    % rax += offset of virtual base class A
ret
```

However, in the constructor of B, the vtable of the *this object is not set to the vtable of class C. Thus when it gets the offset of virtual base class A from the vtable, it reads some junk value and calculates an invalid address for a.

I'm well aware, I could also modify the constructor of B to: B(A* a) {} and that would work. However, this option is not possible for me as this example is a reduced version of a larger system.

I added another virtual class to C and it still works correctly in ICC and MSVC:
[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nvnfzqM5z)

Comment: Do you know what happens when you call a virtual function from the baseclass constructor? I.e. does it call the base or derived implementation? I don't find it strange that the types themselves reflect this when casting pointers.

Comment: This code gives me a headache. What is it supposed to do? And why?

Comment: @PeteBecker It's a reduced version of a CRTP system.The CRTP class essentially has to update values in previously constructed bases (which are known). For that, it has to be able to get a pointer to the bases. In simple terms, all i'm trying to do is to be able to get pointers to bases we have constructed already in an object. In the above code, we have constructed base A and I want to get a pointer to it during construction of another base class B<C>

Comment: @PeteBecker It works fine for GCC/Clang if I make the base class A non virtual. I could restrict the system to non-virtual bases. However, I'm still not sure if my ode is legal.

Comment: The constructor of `A` does not know that there is any `B` around. It’s constructing an object of type `A`. The constructor of `B` does not know that there is any `A` around. It’s constructing an object of type `B`. The only class that knows there are both an `A` and. `B` is `C`. Any base.pointer construction-time shenanigans have to be done in `C`’s constructor, because it knows where the `A` and `B` sub-objects are.

Comment: Note that “it works fine” means only that it hasn’t crashed. Try reversing the order of the bases, or adding a data member to `B`, or both.

Comment: I think the template is a red herring, you should get the same behaviour if it is just `B`, and you use `C` where you have `T`  (and rearrange position of `B::B` to be after `C` definition)

Comment: @M.M I put template for B because static_cast/pointer conversion needs complete type. If I remove the template then static_cast is ill-formed as it doesn't know definition of C. templating B delays its instantiation when we have complete definition of C then static_cast in B constructor are also well-formed

Comment: @YoungBajwa it's not ill-formed with the template removed , [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9sd3so5na).  The static_cast downcast can be used at any point the target type's definition is visible

Comment: @PeteBecker I test with a random hierarchy/classes generator that randomises classes data members and assigns all sorts of bases with different accesses (private/protected/public) aswell as virtual randomness. That's how I found this case on GCC. I tested it various times with different hierarchies and it did not crash or do anything unexpected without virtual bases. Because it knows how to do this conversion `A* a = cp;` at compile time. With virtual it is different.

Answer (score 1):

The code has Undefined Behavior, so it is not surprising that you get different results with different compilers. The UB comes from having to access data that is part of the `C` class before the `C` object has been constructed. That access is necessary during the pointer conversion required by `A* a = cp;`, because the location of the `A` subobject relative to the `C` subobject can change.

As an example of how it can change, consider this larger class hierarchy:

```
struct D: virtual A {
};

struct E: D, C {
};
```

This would result in a class that looks something like:

```
    A
   / \
  /   B
 D    |
  \   C
   \ /
    E
```

This problem started with the cast from the base with `T* cp = static_cast<T*>(this);`. `this` is a `B` object (nothing more, nothing less), but you're telling the compiler that it is really a `C` object, which it isn't (yet). It won't become a `C` object until after the constructor of the `B` subobject finishes running and the body of the `C` constructor starts executing.

Comment: @YoungBajwa Right. Everything got jumbled in my head as I looked into this. I've removed that part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is covered by N4860 [class.cdtor]/1:

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior.

In this code, `A* a = cp;` refers to the base class of the object `c` before the constructor `C()` has been entered for that object.

Related clauses (but not directly applicable), [class.cdtor]/3 and [basic.life]/6.

Comment: Do you want to say that a constructor of `C` is entered only when the constructor's _compound-statement_ is entered?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes. Otherwise I can't find any clause to cover this case but it clearly should be UB as per the other answer's rationale .

Comment: I saw that too but I'm not sure how to interpret it. When is constructor considered to have begun execution? do they mean when body of C() starts executing? In that case, what about: `struct A; struct B { B(A* d); }; struct A {}; struct D : A, B { D() : B((A*)this) {} };` B(A*) gets called before D() is executed, is that then undefined behaviour?

Comment: If CWG1517's proposed resolution [still] correctly expresses the intent of the committee, I'd say that segfault is a compiler bug.